# Trying to relocate of a word using a multi-line regular expression

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to change a file with struct definitions like:

**"typedef struct PET_fun1 { ...  } "** to have definitions like this:

**"typedef struct { ...  } PET_fun1;"**

```
  str = <<END
  typedef struct PET_fun1 { 
     char tam[1];
     char tma[2];
     char mta[2];
  }

  typedef struct PET_fun2 { 
     def : abc[3]
     def : bac[3]
     def : acb[3]
  }

  typedef struct PET_fun3 { 
     abc
  }

  typedef struct PET_fun4 { 
     ...
  }
  END

  puts str.gsub(/(typedef\s+struct\s+)(PET_\w+) ({.*})/m, '\1\3\2') # This regular expression isn't working.
```

The output I want after a successful string transformation would look like this:

```
  typedef struct { 
     char tam[1];
     char tma[2];
     char mta[2];
  } PET_fun1;

  typedef struct { 
     def : abc[3]
     def : bac[3]
     def : acb[3]
  } PET_fun2;

  typedef struct { 
     abc
  } PET_fun3;

  typedef struct { 
     ...
  } PET_fun4;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.*` element is greedy, it's matching all the way from the very first `{` in the string on line 1 to the last `}` in the string on the last line. You need to use a [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) so that the regex stops at the first `}` it finds.

You also probably want `PET_` to bring its preceeding space with it.

Your final regex should look something like this:

```
str.gsub(/(typedef\s+struct\s*)( PET_\w+)( {.*?})/m, '\1\3\2')
```

Comment: Ah shoot that almost works for my entire problem. The problem I have now is that I would also need to ignore nested pairs of {...} inside the main structure. I'll still set yours as the right answer because I didn't account for that in the original problem.

Comment: For matched nested {...}, I'd recommend looking at [regex recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html)

Comment: Good one. You forgot to include  `, '\1\3\2'` between `/m` and `)`.

Comment: `/(typedef\s+struct\s+)(PET_\w+)\s+(\{[^}]+\})/` is less greedy and might be better.

Answer (score 1):

This answer permits nested braces in each "typedef block". The idea is to split the string on the blank lines that separate the "typedef blocks", manipulate the string comprising each block and then join them back into a single string with a blank line between each adjacent pair. By doing it this way, in each block we can search for the closing brace (`'}'`) greedily, thereby permitting nested braces.

**Code**

```
R = /
    (?<=typedef\sstruct) # match 'typedef struct' in a positive lookbehind
    (\s+\w+)             # match > 0 spaces followed by a word in capture group 1
    (\s+{.+})            # match > 0 spaces, then '{', then any number of any
                         # character, greedily, then '}' in capture group 2
    /xm                  # free-spacing regex definition and multiline modes

def doit(str)
  str.split("\n\n").map { |s| s.sub(R, '\2\1') }.join("\n\n")
end
```

**Example**

```
str = <<END
  typedef struct PET_fun1 { 
     char tam[1];
     { char { tma}[2];} 
     char mta[2];
  }

  typedef struct PET_fun2 { 
     def : abc[3]
     def : bac[3]
     def : acb[3]
  }

  typedef struct PET_fun3 { 
     abc
  }

  typedef struct PET_fun4 { 
     ...
  }
END
```

Now execute `doit` with this string.

```
puts doit(str)
  #  typedef struct { 
  #     char tam[1];
  #     { char { tma}[2];} 
  #     char mta[2];
  #  } PET_fun1
  #
  #  typedef struct { 
  #     def : abc[3]
  #     def : bac[3]
  #     def : acb[3]
  #  } PET_fun2
  #
  #  typedef struct { 
  #     abc
  #  } PET_fun3
  #
  #  typedef struct { 
  #     ...
  #  } PET_fun4
```

**Explanation**

The three steps are as follows.

```
a = str.split("\n\n")
  #=> ["  typedef struct PET_fun1 { \n     char tam[1];\n     { char { tma}[2];} \n     char mta[2];\n  }",
  #    "  typedef struct PET_fun2 { \n     def : abc[3]\n     def : bac[3]\n     def : acb[3]\n  }",
  # "  typedef struct PET_fun3 { \n     abc\n  }", "  typedef struct PET_fun4 { \n     ...\n  }\n"]
```

Next,

```
b = a.map { |s| s.sub(R, '\2\1') }
  #=> ["  typedef struct { \n     char tam[1];\n     { char { tma}[2];} \n     char mta[2];\n  } PET_fun1",
  #    "  typedef struct { \n     def : abc[3]\n     def : bac[3]\n     def : acb[3]\n  } PET_fun2",
  #    "  typedef struct { \n     abc\n  } PET_fun3", "  typedef struct { \n     ...\n  } PET_fun4\n"]
```

Lastly,

```
b.join("\n\n")
```

gives us the string returned in the example.